# Use of AtomicBoolean required in RetryWhen

Tags: kotlin, thread-safety, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

In the Javadoc example of `Observable.retryWhen`, `AtomicInteger` is used for `counter` instead of a simpler regular `Int`. Is this actually necessary? Under what circumstances can `errors` emit on a different thread?

My reading the docs and source indicate that the `takeWhile` and `flatMap` closures are always guaranteed to run on same thread.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

```
Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("subscribing"))
     .map(v -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
     .retryWhen(errors -> {
         AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
         return errors
                   .takeWhile(e -> counter.getAndIncrement() != 3)
                   .flatMap(e -> {
                       System.out.println("delay retry by " + counter.get() + " second(s)");
                       return Observable.timer(counter.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                   });
     })
     .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

Comment: The code wouldn't compile if it was an int, because a captured local variable must be effectively final.

Comment: It's not a problem in Kotlin. Just declare as `var counter = 0`

Comment: Sure, but what you posted is Java, not Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary but some get a heart attack when they see a one element int array used for the counter, hence the `AtomicInteger`.

```
 Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("subscribing"))
 .map(v -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
 .retryWhen(errors -> {
     int[] counter = { 0 };
     return errors
               .takeWhile(e -> counter[0]++ != 3)
               .flatMap(e -> {
                   System.out.println("delay retry by " + counter[0] + " second(s)");
                   return Observable.timer(counter[0], TimeUnit.SECONDS);
               });
 })
 .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

> Under what circumstances can errors emit on a different thread?

The handler sequence can have its own threading so whenever you have shared external access to mutable state, you should make sure accessing that is thread safe. In the example, again, it is not necessary as the particular combination during the usage of the counter is running on a single thread and guaranteed not overlapping itself as any new error can only happen after the current sequence signaled the retry to happen.

Comment: Even if `errors` was an arbitrary observable doesn't the Reactive streams spec guarantee that those callbacks are called serially? Like you never have to worry about synchronizing code inside an `onNext` callback because it is always called serially.

Comment: The counter is external to the error handling sequence thus you have to worry about concurrent access.

Comment: If `takeWhile` and `flatMap` are always called serially (never can one thread be in `takeWhile` and another thread in `flatMap` or more than one thread in `takeWhile` or `flatMap` at the same time) than I do not see why we have to worry about concurrent access. I just want to make sure I understand thread safety in Rx.

Comment: The Javadoc's aim is to help user understand the operator with a ready-to-run example. Users tend to copy-paste such examples, modify them to their needs and given that AtomicInteger is used, they will not likely encounter any issues with the counter. If one has the sufficient experience, properties such as guaranteed synchronicity can be deduced and the code can be optimized to take advantage of it.